# ReCaptcha (Invisible) execute callback is not firing with multiple widget instances

Tags: javascript, callback, recaptcha, onload

I had reCaptcha running on contact forms that trigger by AJAX (Naturally, to use the ReCaptcha server side verification via PHP `curl()`) for a while.

I've tried to update the javascript triggers to enable multiple forms on one page.
Now, even with just one form per page, the grecaptcha.execute() does not appear to return the call back function at all.

There's no value assigned to the tag `<textarea class="g-recaptcha-response">` either after executing (even by manual run on console!).

Here's what I got:

Step A: Calling in the JS Library (I call this as the LAST javascript file, after my common.js file is loaded).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=en" defer async></script>
```

The HTML Code witih public key, and callback function set to `CaptchaExecSubmit();`:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcy4ywUAAAAAKAnjq5c2iaSbVNFMvcot700cHKv" data-callback="CaptchaExecSubmit" data-theme="light" data-size="invisible" data-badge="inline"></div>
```

Enabler in my `common.js` is as below.
The library from google is called with `onload=CaptchaCallback` as the attribute to execute upon deferred async loading of the reCaptcha library.

```
// Render each recaptcha. 
window.CaptchaCallback = function(){
    $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
        var recaptcha_widget_callback = $(el).data('callback');
        console.log()
        var attributes = {
            'sitekey'  : $(el).data('sitekey'),
            'size'     : $(el).data('size'),
            'callback' : recaptcha_widget_callback
        };
        var recaptcha_widget_id = grecaptcha.render(el, attributes);
        $(el).data('recaptcha-widget-id', recaptcha_widget_id);
        // assign unique ID to each instance of it, so that multiple recaptcha instances can be initiated.
        console.log('setting ID for recaptcha sequence: '+recaptcha_widget_id+' with call back '+recaptcha_widget_callback);
    });
}

window.CaptchaExecSubmit = function(captcha_response) {
    console.log('invisible captcha verified, activate form '+window.activeForm);
    console.log('Captcha exsec response: '+captcha_response)
    window.recaptchaverified = 1;
    activate_ajaxemailform($(window.activeForm));
    return true;
}
```

CaptchaCallback(); seems to be running fine, widget IDs and callback definitions are good. (Console says `"setting ID for recaptcha sequence: 0 with call back CaptchaExecSubmit"`).

Then, attaching the behaviour on each form element (with class `.emailform`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emailform').each(function(){
        var thisform = $(this);
        var thisform_id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('Activating emailform '+thisform_id);

        $(this).submit(function(e){
            var captcha = $(this).find('.g-recaptcha');
            var callback = captcha.data('callback');
            e.preventDefault();
            var captcha_widget_id = captcha.data('recaptcha-widget-id');// this captcha instance.. usually 0, 1 etc. base don sequence of load.
            console.log('Captcha callback: '+callback+' From widget sequence '+captcha_widget_id);
            // If captcha is invisible then enable the test verification before submitting the form
            if ((typeof captcha !== "undefined") && (captcha.data('size') === 'invisible')) {
                window.activeForm = thisform; // Stores current form so we can submit it later
                console.log("Setting active form to "+thisform_id);
                grecaptcha.execute(captcha_widget_id);
                var g_response = thisform.find('.g-recaptcha-response').val();
                // Captcha check, this will run enable_contact_submit_invisible() as a callback if successful.
                console.log('grecaptcha.execute on ID '+ captcha_widget_id+', g_reponse: '+g_response);
                return false;
            } else {
                return activate_ajaxemailform(thisform);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

When I manually run `grecaptcha.execute(0);` it runs, returns some complex looking object, but the `textarea.g-recaptcha-response` is still empty, and the callback of `CaptchaExecSubmit();` still does not run.

Then, tried manually run `CaptchaExecSubmit();` on console, the form submission DOES work fine - except that the `textarea.g-recaptcha-response` value is empty, so it just fails the server-side test.

[image]

I'm about 4 hours into this, losing my sanity. Help please.

I realize at this point I have a lot of vars declared then console logged and a tad messy - I want to leave no stone unturned, check every single bit before calling out for help.

Answer (score 0):

... make sure you check the ReCaptcha key version to be V3, not V2.

I'm shocked that the RECAPTCHA library doesn't return an error saying the key is not eligible for the new one.

This site, I had running for a long time. Whole 4 hours, it never occurred to me to check the API Key attached in the recaptcha console. It was the old one.